# onkeyup event in textarea

Tags: javascript, dom-events, textarea, onkeyup

I have a very basic input/output structure in HTML:

```
<textarea id="input" onkeyup="sendCode()">
Hello World!
</textarea> 

<div id="output"></div>
```

And I have JS function that should pass everything from input to output:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function sendCode(){
 output.innerHTML = input.innerHTML;
}
```

The `sendCode()` function works when I call it manually, but it seems that `onkeyup` event not firing in this textarea.

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mudroljub/y5a2n8ab/

Any help?

**UPDATE**: jsfiddle is updated and working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use value since it's not a content text but a value property

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function sendCode(){
 output.innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

And a working [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhdtb0u4/1/)

Comment: @DamanDaman If it's the best answer for you, you can mark it as accepted to let others know np

Answer (score 2):

Basically java script is not that dynamic.So a better option is to 
use jQuery.

[Note:- "jquery-2.2.2.min.js" given in src, in script tag,
is Jquery Library file codes can be copied from following link :http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js]

Just copy the contents from above link,into a textfile , save it by the name "jquery-2.2.2.min.js" 
or any other name as you wish.The src of script should contain the same.
The "jquery-2.2.2.min.js" should be in the same directory where
you have the html file. Otherwise full path to be mentioned.

Here is the answer to your question.

```
    <html>
     <head>
       <title>Dynamic TextArea</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function(){
                     $("textarea").keyup(function(){
                           sendCode();
                     });
             });

             function sendCode(){
                  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
                  document.getElementById("input").value;
             }
       </script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <form>
              <textarea id="input">
                      Hello World!
              </textarea> 
        </form>
        <span id="output"></span>
     </body>
    </html>
```

If you have any doubts please ask.
I am sure once you learn to use jQuery you would forget javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I would first like to point out that this will not run because the code runs before the HTML exists, so first off, put these lines inside a function:

```
window.onload= function anyname() {
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
}
```

Secondly, try using either:

```
editor.onkeyup = "sendCode()"
```

in your script area or at the top of the new function i created:

```
editor.addEventListener(keyup,sendCode,false)
```

Basically when a key goes up in that area it calls the `sendCode()` function. The false is if you don't want to use capture which I think is default anyway but just to be safe.

Comment: I think this answer is the most complete and scientific way to address this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you define the `sendCode()` function? It might not exist at the point where you create your text area.

This snippet should work:

```
<textarea id="editor">
    Hello World!
</textarea> 
<div id="output"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
    var output = document.getElementById("output");

    function sendCode(){
     output.innerHTML = editor.value;
    }
    editor.addEventListener('keyup',sendCode);
</script>
```